# Python - in place list partition

Tags: python

Is there a way to partition list by predicate in place using standard python 2.7( c++ STL std::partition style) ? Something like `group_by` from `itertools` but without crating additional arrays ? I need to recursively partition array into two groups, based on variadic conditions and I am limited by the amount of RAM.

What I am looking for is a function like:

`partitionCPPStyle(data, startIndex, endIndex, condition)`

which would result in `data[startIndex:endIndex]` list having all elements satisfying the condition at the beginning and returning the index of first element that doesn't fullfil the condition. No copies, as little extra memory used as possible.

I've ended up writing my own implementation:

```
def partitionInPlace(data, startIndex, endIndex, predicate):
    swapIndex = endIndex
    index = startIndex
    while(index < swapIndex):
        if not predicate(data[index]):
            temp = data[swapIndex]
            data[swapIndex] = data[index]
            data[index] = temp
            swapIndex = swapIndex-1
        else:
            index = index+1
    return index
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: The iterator tools won't copy the list or am i completely wrong? But if you plan on deleting items in a list you will have to create a new list some how seeing as lists are immutable and can't be changed. Maybe have a look at `dicts` or [ctype.array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#arrays)s - maybe you can do something with those?

Comment: @Torxed lists are mutable.

Comment: @roganjosh Yea sorry, you're right. I mixed lists up with `tuple` in my head.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy to implement - but since you have the "condition" (I will use  the term "predicate" from here on) there is a complication: for no copying at all,  the only way the resulting structure can "know" if an item attends to the specific predicate is to check it at access time - that means you will have "holes" in your indexing.

That is easier to understand given an example:

```
a = list(range(20))
b = SlicedList(a, slice(10, 20), predicate=lambda x: x%2
len(b) # will correctly report (5)
b[0] # will raise ValueError as "10" fails the predicate
# so, 0-9 are valid indexes for "b", but only the contents 
# that attend the predicate will actually return a value
# you can safely iterate on b with a "for", though:
for item in b:
    print(item)  # (11, 13, 15, 17, 19)
```

For iteration, though, it should work nicely.

```
try:
    from collections.abc import MutableSequence
except ImportError:
    from collections import MutableSequence


class SlicedList(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, data, slice=None, predicate=None):
        self.data = data
        if not slice:
            slice = __builtins__.slice(0, len(data), 1)
        self.slice = slice
        self.predicate = predicate

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index < 0:
            raise NotImplementedError("Can't use negative indexes on Sliced lists")
        real_index = self.slice.start + index * (self.slice.step or 1)
        item = self.data[real_index]
        if self.predicate and not self.predicate(item):
            raise ValueError("Item at position {} does not attend the predicate".format(index))
        return item

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        ...

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        ...

    def __len__(self):
        if not self.predicate:
            start, stop, step = self.slice.indices(len(data))
            return (stop - start) // (step or 1)
        count = 0
        for i in range(self.slice.start, self.slice.stop, self.slice.step or 1):
            if self.predicate(self.data[i]):
                count += 1
        return count

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.slice.start, self.slice.stop, self.slice.step or 1):
            value =self.data[i]
            if not self.predicate or self.predicate(value):
                yield i

    def insert(self, position, value):
        ...
```

Another hint for you is to quit Python 2.7 as soon as possible - all modern libraries and frameworks run Ok on Python 3 and Python 2 is getting really aged these days. The code bellow will work on both, but I had to make a provision for it.